# How to create collapsible using digraph or D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dagre-d3, dagre

I want to create collapsible digraph using dagre.js. But it generates static graphs with no click events. I want to toggle children of a node when user click on the graph node.

any help will be appreciated..